# Programmatically adding columns to DataList

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist

I have a C# ASP.NET Web Form page.
I want to be able to run custom queries and display the results of the queries in a list or gridview. Basically I want to run a query like "select * from [tablename]" and display the results on my Web Form page.
The problem is if I want to run custom queries then I have to add the columns to the DataList manually, and it's just not working for me!

As far as I know, I'm supposed to add columns using:

```
DataList.Controls.Add([columnhere]);
```

But when I try to do something like:

```
DataList.Controls.Add(new DataColumn("Name"));
```

It gives me an error related to the type of Control. I have to use a Web.UI Control. And all the ones I know of are for Win Forms applications.

So my question is this: How do I populate a DataList with the data that I get with my SqlDataAdapter? (With adding the columns and everything)
I want a C# solution, not an HTML/ASP solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedatalist.controls(v=vs.110).aspx), you will see how you can add a column to your DataList. Example:

```
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("IntegerValue", typeof(Int32)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("StringValue", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("CurrencyValue", typeof(double)));
```

Comment: Seems to me that that is for DataTables, not DataList.

Comment: @user3759355 look at the MSDN article referenced, it works for DataTables **and** DataList. Try it yourself ;)